# write java program

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class treasure
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {


     Scanner variable=new Scanner(System.in);

     int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j;
a=variable.nextInt();
b=variable.nextInt();
c=variable.nextInt();
d=variable.nextInt();
e=variable.nextInt();
f=variable.nextInt();
g=variable.nextInt();
h=variable.nextInt();
i=variable.nextInt();
j=variable.nextInt();
while(variable%2==0)
{

          System.out.println("its an even number"+a);
System.out.println("its an even number"+b);
System.out.println("its an even number"+c);
System.out.println("its an even number"+d);
System.out.println("its an even number"+e);
System.out.println("its an even number"+f);
System.out.println("its an even number"+g);
System.out.println("its an even number"+h);
System.out.println("its an even number"+i);
System.out.println("its an even number"+j);

}

System.out.println("its an odd number");
}

}
```

write java program to read 10 int numbers during run time test for odd or even 
(if it even print out even number otherwise odd number) 
i'm only allowed to use (while- do while - for)

Comment: What's your question? When you just dump code and a description of your assignment, it appears that you were too lazy to even bother asking a coherent question or even telling us what the problem is to begin with.

Comment: this is my first programming course and i still not take counter yet or how to use if with while

Comment: That has nothing to do with the issues I've pointed out.

Comment: i was clear enough and i wrote my question "write java program to read 10 int numbers during run time test for odd or even (if it even print out even number otherwise odd number) i'm only allowed to use (while- do while - for)"   under my code 

and if i can't understand what are you saying clearly that is because English is not my first language

Comment: That's just pasting your homework. A program description is not a question. We can't understand what you're having trouble with if you don't ask an actual question.

Comment: ok i got your point and i'll work on it in my next questions

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm in the mood of doing homework assignments ! Your code should be like :

```
Scanner variable=new Scanner(System.in);
int counter=0;
while(counter<10) {
   if(variable.nextInt()%2==0){
       System.out.println("its an even number.");
   } else {
       System.out.println("its an odd number.");
   }
        counter++;
}
```

Comment: this is my first programming course and i still not take counter yet or how to use if with while